# Что такое "TOPIX compression mode”?

Tags: java, print

Я пытаюсь печатать на термопринтере TOSHIBA (TPCL язык, JAVA/Kotlin, Android), когда печатаю несжатый BMP файлы, принтер слишком долго думает перед печатью, из под Windows программы печати этикеток печатают в режиме TOPIX и это происходит намного быстрее. Может быть кто-то знает какие-нибудь библиотеки сжатия BMP в TOPIX? Или хотя бы где можно найти документацию по TOPIX. Вообще ничего не могу найти по этому вопросу, может быть у TOPIX есть другое название?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63203773/13970074

Comment: Сколько цветов в bmp?

Comment: монохромный bmp